# Use recode function with %like% operator

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there anyway to use the recode function from `dplyr` with the %like% operator from `DescTools`, as well as with an 'other' statement? i.e. what is shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DescTools)

dat <- data.frame(NAME = c("Bill", "Billy", "Wibill", "Chris"))

dat %>%
  mutate(NAME_2 = recode(NAME, "%Bill%" = "Willhelm", "Other"))
```

Desired output is:

```
NAME      NAME_2
Bill      Willhelm
Billy     Willhelm
Wibill    Willhelm
Chris     Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `recode()` works; `recode()` matches specific values with specific replacements. However, your desired output is easy to achieve with `mutate()` and `if_else()`:

```
dat %>%
    mutate(NAME_2 = if_else(NAME %like% "%[Bb]ill%", "Willhelm", "Other"))

    NAME   NAME_2
1   Bill Willhelm
2  Billy Willhelm
3 Wibill Willhelm
4  Chris    Other
```

(Though you'll notice I've had to account for upper- or lower-case "Bill", which would be the case with any use of `%like%` if your desired output is not case sensitive in that way.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `grepl` in `base R`

```
dat$NAME_2 <- with(dat, ifelse(grepl("Bill", NAME, ignore.case = TRUE), "Willhelm", "Other"))
```